Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed Problem using PDFBox
I'm trying to sign a pdf using a Hsm Service that receives the document hash and responds with the signed hash. I followed some examples and checked posts in Stack OverFlow that related some similar problems but yet i did not found the solution. Here stays a quick flow of the data:

Receive the pdf in byte64 - Create a PDDocumemt and add a visual Signature
Use externalSigning object to get the data hash and send it to be signed.
Use sign method to add certificates and the signed hash

When receiving the pdf on my consuming app i get a signed pdf yet the signature is not valid... It shows "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed". I already try to find the source of the problem but with no success, i do not change the document after the sign method, only do the necessary to get the bytes from the file to send it in the response.
I know that are similar discussions but non of them solved my problem.
Here is the majoraty of my code that handles the signing process:
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(request.getRequest().getFile());
            
float page_width = doc.getPage(page).getMediaBox().getWidth();
float page_height = doc.getPage(page).getMediaBox().getHeight();

// Calculate position for signature
float sqr_width = page_width / num_cols;
float sqr_height = page_height / num_rows;
float pos_X = page_width - sqr_width - (sqr_width * (num_cols - column));
float pos_Y = page_height - sqr_height - (sqr_height * (num_rows - row));

GetCertificatebyTotpIDOutput certificateBody= getCertificate();     


PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();
signature.setFilter( PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE );
signature.setSubFilter( PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
signature.setReason( "Test" );
signature.setSignDate(Calendar.getInstance());

Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(); 
humanRect.setFrame(new Point2D.Float(pos_X, pos_Y), new Dimension((int) sqr_width, (int) sqr_height));

PDRectangle rect = createSignatureRectangle(doc, humanRect);

InputStream template = createVisualSignatureTemplate( doc, page, rect, signature, certificateBody ); // Implementation defined below.
SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();
options.setVisualSignature( template );
options.setPage(0);
options.setPreferredSignatureSize(9000);

doc.addSignature( signature, options );


FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = doc.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(outputStream);

byte[] input = IOUtils.toByteArray(externalSigning.getContent());
byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(input);
String digest = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(hash));

System.out.println("Before signing: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(hash)));

byte[] signedContent3 = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
byte[] hash3 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(signedContent3);
System.out.println("File OS hash: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(hash3)));


SigFinalizeOutput signedDoc = signDocument(certificateBody.getCertAlias(), "test_pdf", digest, "test", totpID, totp);
String base64HashSig = signedDoc.getSignedDocsInfo().get(0).getHashSig();

byte[] cmsSignature = sign(externalSigning.getContent(), base64HashSig);

externalSigning.setSignature(cmsSignature);

and the sign method:
public byte[] sign(InputStream content, String signedHash) throws IOException {

    // cannot be done private (interface)
    try {
        GetCertificatebyTotpIDOutput certificateBody= getCertificate(); 
        String base64CertificateString = certificateBody.getCert_64();

//        byte[] certificateBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64CertificateString);
//        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
//        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(certificateBytes));

        byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64CertificateString);
        Collection collection = null;
        try {
            collection = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificates(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
        } catch (CertificateException e) {

        }
          
        Certificate[] certChain = new Certificate[collection.size()];
        Iterator iterator = collection.iterator();
        int i = 0;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            certChain[i++] = (Certificate) iterator.next();
        }
        
        // Certificate chain is acquired at initialization
        List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Certificate cert : certChain) {
            certList.add(cert);
        }
        Store certStore= new JcaCertStore(certList);
        org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate cert = org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Certificate.getInstance(certChain[0].getEncoded());
        
        X509Certificate signerCert = (X509Certificate) certChain[0];
        CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
        gen.addCertificates(certStore);
      
        byte[] input = IOUtils.toByteArray(content);


        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        messageDigest.update(input);
        System.out.println("During signing: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(messageDigest.digest())));
        Attribute attr = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(messageDigest.digest())));
        ASN1EncodableVector v = new ASN1EncodableVector();
        v.add(attr);

        ContentSigner contentSigner = new ContentSigner() {
            
            @Override
            public byte[] getSignature() {
                 System.out.println(String.valueOf(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedHash)));
                return Base64.getDecoder().decode(signedHash);
            }

            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutputStream() {
                return new ByteArrayOutputStream() ;
            }

            @Override
            public AlgorithmIdentifier getAlgorithmIdentifier() {
                return new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find("SHA256WITHDSA");
            }
        };

        SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new BcDigestCalculatorProvider())
                .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(new AttributeTable(v)));
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(builder.build(contentSigner, new X509CertificateHolder(cert)));
        //gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().build()).build(contentSigner, signerCert));
        
        
        CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(content);
        
        CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = gen.generate(msg, true);
        byte[] result =cmsSignedData.getEncoded();

        return result;

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | CMSException | OperatorCreationException e) {
        throw new IOException(e);
    }
}

i tried calculate the byte range but then i saw that externalsigning.getcontent() already retrieves only the value from the pdf without the signature object.
hope some one can help me on at least what to check next.

Please share a PDF signed by your code. Analyzing such an example usually points quite directly to the issue while there are many many possible causes for a "Document has been altered or corrupted since it was signed".

Having asked for an example PDF signed by your code, I looked through your code and recognized some issues. Most likely not all of them, though.
Incorrect use of MessageDigest class
You do
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        messageDigest.update(input);
        System.out.println("During signing: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(messageDigest.digest())));
        Attribute attr = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(messageDigest.digest())));

But if you read the JavaDocs of the MessageDigest.digest() method, you'll find:
    /**
     * Completes the hash computation by performing final operations
     * such as padding. The digest is reset after this call is made.
     *
     * @return the array of bytes for the resulting hash value.
     */
    public byte[] digest() {

So in System.out.println("During signing: " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(messageDigest.digest()))) retrieve the hash value and reset messageDigest. Thus, in your next line Attribute attr = new Attribute(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DERSet(new DEROctetString(messageDigest.digest()))) you retrieve the digest of an empty input!
Signing the wrong hash
You explicitly set a signed attributes generator:
        SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(new BcDigestCalculatorProvider())
                .setSignedAttributeGenerator(new DefaultSignedAttributeTableGenerator(new AttributeTable(v)));

Thus, you are aware that you use a CMS signature container structure with signed attributes. But you don't sign those attribute, you sign the the document data!
Thus, you have to change your code to sign the correct data.

Thank you @mkl for the quick response... Sorry probably these are begginer mistakes. Most of the sign method code was retrieve from examples and questions, so there are parts of the code that i don't fully understand...
Another question, is the problem possible related to broken cross reference table? I'have see some other discussions that talk about that, you reply them inclusevely.

Also i already diffed both hex codes before and after the sign method... the only difference in whole hex code is the /Contents of the Sig object.

Finally for signing the correct data... How do i use the contentSigner so i can add the signedHash that i receive from the HSM service... Should i use another method of the CMSSignedDataGenerator class?

"Another question, is the problem possible related to broken cross reference table?" - In my answer I showed two reasons why your signatures will be broken, no matter what input file you use. Thus, you should focus on fixing those errors first.

"How do i use the contentSigner so i can add the signedHash that i receive from the HSM service... Should i use another method of the CMSSignedDataGenerator class?" - Consider proceeding like in this answer.
